# elasticsearch tokenize into word pairs

Tags: elasticsearch, combinations

given input "quick brown fox jumped", I would like to tokenize to

```
["quick brown", "brown fox" "fox jumped"]
```

But the tokenizers don't seem to offer this feature. This feels like it should be a common feature so I'm guessing im missing something obvious.

I can do ngrams, which allows like of

```
['q', 'qu', 'qui', 'quic', 'quick']
```

But I would like to get the combinations for words, rather than letters.

Is this supported?

Ps, the reason I would like to do this is to do suggesting next word - similarly to how google suggests the next word to use. I intend to use this tokenizer with phrase suggestor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah it turns out I want [shingles](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html).